# "sed" to add a space only under a certain condition

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

I have to add a space after the # to every occurrence, only if the # is at the beginning of the line and after the # there is at least one character that is not the space. For example this code:

```
echo "# ok" | sed "s|^#[^ ]|# |g"
```

Returns `# ok` as expected, but this code:

```
echo "#ok" | sed "s|^#[^ ]|# |g"
```

Returns `# k` and not `# ok` as expected.
How do I get the `# ok` output?

Edit:

This is the code that solves my problem, thanks to @FedonKadifeli:

```
echo -e "#ok\n# ok\n #ok\n#ok #ok\n##ok #ok"
```

Returns:

```
#ok
# ok
 #ok
#ok #ok
##ok #ok
```

This code:

```
echo -e "#ok\n# ok\n #ok\n#ok #ok\n##ok #ok" | sed -r 's|^#(#*)([^[:space:]#])|#\1 \2|g'
```

Returns:

```
# ok
# ok
 #ok
# ok #ok
## ok #ok
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One fairly straightforward approach would be to replace the first "hash" by "hash space" only in lines that begin with "hash not space":

```
$ echo "#ok" | sed "/^#[^ ]/s|#|# |"
# ok
```

In regex variants that provide it, like Perl, you could use *negative lookahead*:

```
$ echo "#ok" | perl -pe 's/^#(?! )/# /'
# ok
```

Comment: stelldriver goodmorning. I want this `echo "#ok" | sed "/^#[^ ]/s|#|# |"` sintax equivalent in perl.

Comment: @MarioPalumbo you could use `perl -pe "s|#|# | if /^#[^ ]/"`

Comment: with two substitution istead? for example `perl -pe "(s|#|# | and s|*|* |) if /^#[^ ]/"` doesn't work

Comment: Well `*` isn't a valid perl regex - what are you trying to match exactly? If you want to match a literal `*` you'd need `s|\*|* |`

Comment: literal *       ........

Comment: was "and" instead than "or" the problem. Thank you. Sorry for the silly questions

Comment: if i want use "*" as "all characters after the word", how do you do? In another example.

Comment: @MarioPalumbo in regex, `*` is a *quantifier*, meaning "zero or more of the preceding things". To match zero or more single *characters*, use `.*`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `sed` "[back-reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions.html)" like this:

```
sed -r 's/^#([^ ])/# \1/'
```

Comment: I have solved it! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that solves my problem, thanks to @steeldriver and @FedonKadifeli:

```
echo -e "#ok\n#ok\n# ok\n# ok\n#ok\nnobegin #ok"
```

Returns:

```
#ok
#ok
# ok
# ok
#ok
nobegin #ok
```

This code:

```
echo -e "#ok\n#ok\n# ok\n# ok\n#ok\nnobegin #ok" | sed "\|^#[^[:space:]]|s|#|# |g"
```

Or this more logic code:

```
echo -e "#ok\n#ok\n# ok\n# ok\n#ok\nnobegin #ok" | sed -r "s|^#([^[:space:]])|# \1|g"
```

Returns:

```
# ok
# ok
# ok
# ok
# ok
nobegin #ok
```

Comment: Edit your Q instead.