# Show all lines before a match

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep

I want to show all lines before a match, not only 10, or 7, or 14 for example, as explained in [How do I fetch lines before/after the grep result in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444808/how-do-i-fetch-lines-before-after-the-grep-result-in-bash/12444813).

How can I do it? It doesn't matter if the matched line is included or not.

For example, instead of:

```
... | grep -B 10 -- "foo"
```

I want:

```
... | grep -B -- "foo"
```

But this last code doesn't work.

Comment: When I have published a reply in this topic: `https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277701`
i have received this comment:
`Edit your Q instead. – bac0n Sep 25 at 13:02`
Make up your minds on what is best to do.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

- Including the match,

  ```
  sed '/foo/q' file
  ```

  It is better to **q**uit `sed` as soon as a match is found, otherwise `sed` would keep reading the file and wasting your time, which would be considerable for large files.
- Excluding the match,

  ```
  sed -n '/foo/q;p' file
  ```

  The `-n` flag means that only lines that reach the `p` command will be printed. Since the `foo` line triggers the `q`uit action, it does not reach `p` and thus is not printed.

  - If your `sed` is GNU's, this can be simplified to

    ```
    sed '/foo/Q' file
    ```

**References**

1. `/foo/` — [Addresses](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Addresses-overview.html)
2. `q`, `p` — [Often-used commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Common-Commands.html)
3. `Q` — [GNU Sed extended commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Extended-Commands.html)
4. `-n` — [Command-line options](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Command_002dLine-Options.html)

Comment: With GNU sed, there's also `Q` to quit without default-printing the matched line

Comment: there is the `perl` alternative? Is more kind.

Comment: @MarioPalumbo `perl -pe 'exit if /foo/'`; similarly `awk '/foo/{exit} 1'`

Comment: @steeldriver you are genius. Your reply is the V green reply. Comment this as answer

Comment: Can i have an example of OS with no-GNU sed?

Comment: @MarioPalumbo OSes are not bound to a specific version of Sed. BSD and Mac by default don't use GNU Sed. Also minimal systems (e.g. Busybox) don't feature GNU Sed. Since it has many extensions, it is larger.

Answer (score 9):

With GNU sed. Print all lines, from the first to the line with the required string.

```
sed '0,/foo/!d' file
```

Comment: This worked even with pipefail set, where `q` caused problems for me.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution with `sed`, given the content of file.txt:

```
bar
baz
moo
foo
loo
zoo
```

command including pattern

```
tac file.txt | sed -n '/foo/,$p' | tac
```

output

```
bar
baz
moo
foo
```

excluding pattern

```
tac file.txt | sed -n -e '/foo/,$p' | tac | sed -n '/foo/!p'

bar
baz
moo
```

Comment: What is `tac`? Perhaps `cat`?

Comment: `tac` is a reverse `cat` ;)

Comment: Wow. I've been using UNIX off-&-on (mostly on) for almost 30 years, & never heard of "tac" before today. There's always something new to learn.

Answer (score 4):

**FreeBSD** (including MacOS) version does have such feature.

Well `-B -1` works, it shows all the lines before the match from the beginning of the file.

```
... | grep -B -1 -- "foo"
```

Same for `-A -1` , it shows all the lines after the match to the end of the file.

```
... | grep -A -1 -- "foo"
```

May be useful for some, It doesn't work with GNU implementation included within Ubuntu.

Comment: It would be great if they introduced this feature to Ubuntu/Debian as well.

Comment: @MarioPalumbo , That would be great.  I even hope to the hole tool copied both side as extra gnu_* tools on BSD and bsd_* tools on GNU. But it seems hard due to old history of licensing.

Answer (score 4):

To print all lines before the match,

```
perl -pe 'exit if /foo/' file
```

```
awk '/foo/{exit} 1' file
```

Answer (score 3):

Current solutions except schrodigerscatcuriosity's print the file contents even when there's no match. schrodigerscatcuriosity's involves using `tac` and so requires reading the whole input before looking for matches.

Here's another way to do it with just `sed` and printing only when there's a match:

```
sed -n '1h;1!H;/foo/{g;p;q}'
```

- `1h` -- copy pattern space to hold space when on the first line
- `1!H` -- append pattern space to hold space when not on the first line
- `/foo/{...}` -- on matching `/foo/`,

  - `g` -- copy hold space to pattern space
  - `p` -- print pattern space
  - `q` -- quit

Comment: For huge files (a large fraction of your total RAM), if you aren't sure a match exists you might just `grep -q input.txt && sed '/pattern/q  input.txt` to verify a match before running  `sed`.  Or get the line number from `grep` and use it for `head`.  Slower than 1-pass when a match does exist, *unless* it means you avoided swap thrashing.  Also doesn't work as a filter; needs to reopen its input from the start.

Answer (score 3):

> Show ALL lines before a match

You can use large enough number for `-B` option of grep. For example if your know that input size is no more than `999` you can use it with `-B` option:

```
... | grep -B 999 -- "foo"
```